# How to execute a command if two gameobjects are at a certain position?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am struggling with a problem, i couldn't find a solution untill now, maybe you can help me! So, i have a conveyor and random gameobjects spawning on it, and the conveyor transports the objects untill the end of it. On the conveyor i have a sort palette that i want to rotate at certain angles based on what gameobject spawned, but i want them to rotate only when the gameobject is close to the pallet, kind of sensor working thing, like the pallet has a sensor and when the object is at a certain distance, the pallet knows the angle he should rotate on. The objects move on the conveyor on the X axis, I want to know how to check when the gameobject reached the point, the code i am using below is not working. Thank you for your help!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
//i have a conveyor with 2 bands next to eachother moving on opposite directions
public class Stackoverflow : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Slider x;
    public InputField inputspawn;
    public InputField inputtime;
    public Slider z;
    public GameObject[] prefabs;
    Vector3 V = new Vector3();
    public GameObject coordX1, coordX2, coordZ1, coordZ2;
    int spawnvalue;
    float timevalue;
    bool value = false;
    public Slider paleta1;//slider that rotates 1st pallet
    public Slider paleta2;//slider that rotates 2nd pallet
    public GameObject verificationpoint;//when this point is reached by GO, the pallet should rotate

    float[] unghiuri = { 164.6144f, 205.6429f, 87.5875f, 164.6144f };//angles for 1st pallet
    float[] ung = { 154.3571f, 90f, 90f, 90f};// angles for 2nd pallet

    public int T;
    public GameObject paleta1go, paleta2go;// pallet 1 and 2
    public float delta;
    public float dist;

    void Start()
    {
        Vector3 position = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range( coordX1.transform.position.x, coordX2.transform.position.x), 3f, UnityEngine.Random.Range(coordZ1.transform.position.z, coordZ2.transform.position.z));
        T = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, prefabs.Length);
        Instantiate(prefabs[T], position, Quaternion.identity);
        paleta1.value = unghiuri[T];
        paleta2.value = ung[T];
        StartCoroutine(Spawn());
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (value == true)
        {
            Vector3 position = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(coordX1.transform.position.x, coordX2.transform.position.x), 3f, UnityEngine.Random.Range(coordZ1.transform.position.z, coordZ2.transform.position.z));
            V = position;
            spawnvalue = int.Parse(inputspawn.text);
            timevalue = float.Parse(inputtime.text);
            dist = Vector3.Distance(paleta1go.transform.position, prefabs[T].transform.position);
            if (prefabs[T].transform.position.x == verificationpoint.transform.position.x)//that's how i verify if the GO reaches verification point
            {
                paleta1.value = unghiuri[T];
                paleta2.value = ung[T];
            }

        }

    }
    IEnumerator Spawn()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            if(value)
            for(int i = 0; i < spawnvalue; ++i)
            {
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(coordX1.transform.position.x, coordX2.transform.position.x), 3f, UnityEngine.Random.Range(coordZ1.transform.position.z, coordZ2.transform.position.z));
                V = position;
                T = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, prefabs.Length);
                Instantiate(prefabs[T], V, Quaternion.identity);

                }


            yield return new WaitForSeconds(timevalue);


        }
    }
    public void ToggleState(bool t)
    {
        value = !value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked into setting up an invisible cube which makes use of [OnTriggerEnter](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider.OnTriggerEnter.html)? Triggers are a way to detect collisions without affecting physics. Also, when instantiating a given prefab, you might want to assign it to a new object if you need to handle its values -- note the return value of [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) is the actual clone, whereas the passed parameter is the origin object (so you're currently comparing distance to the origin, not the instance).

Comment: I need to spawn a lot of initial objects, and with cloning them it was the only way i found it possible to spawn more of them and to keep them in the scene forever, not to dissapear when i spawn a new one of the same type, i am pretty new to unity, so that's the best i could do by searching over the internet. If i declare a new gameobject and i assign it the prefab, my script could work? That's what are you trying to say? I did not try the OnTriggerEnter yet, that works using the clones?

Comment: Think of prefabs as templates you copy, not something you assign to an object. Using `myNewGameObject = Instantiate(somePrefab, ...)` the new object is created and live in the scene, and its transform -- of the new one, not the prefab -- can then be used for e.g. checking the distance to another. You can then later destroy it when it's not needed anymore. But yes, `OnTriggerEnter` might then be the preferable way to check for conveyor belt positions (though Distance would also work, but importantly, the Distance to the clone and not the origin prefab). Good luck!

Comment: The myNewGameObject = Instantiate is working! Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you tag both C# and UnityScript. You're either using one language or the other, surely?

Comment: Because i use a C# script that i run in unity, it's wrong that i tagged both?

Comment: This is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].